# How to sort an excel sheet according to sort order of my original excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Using chrome extension 'Webscraper.io', I was regularly scraping a government website to track the updated project expenses. Although it was very efficient in its operation, it's failing to return the data in the same order I was providing input Url's. And even more weirdly every time I run the task it was picking a different order even though the source is exactly same. Suppose, if I run the task of 5 url's twice, the output will be (No specific random order):

```
(Day 1) Output  (Day 2) Output
Url 2   $500    Url 3   $478 
Url 4   $867    Url 1   $637 
Url 1   $928    Url 4   $102 
Url 3   $109    Url 5   $942 
Url 5   $208    Url 2   $296
```

[image: Image example]

It makes side by side comparison of different days of data an extremely tedious task to me. So, is there a way to sort columns of sheet 2 according to the sort order of sheet 1? Alphabetical sorting of both the sheets is definitely one option, but it breaks my original order (Which is department wise). Ideally I want to paste column B of all days to my original sheet & then compare the changes.

Comment: For Excel 2010 and above this might be easier with Power Query. Otherwise, you can try with PivotTable.

Comment: Into Cell C2 of sheet1, you could paste =VLOOKUP($A2 Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE). Then copy cell C2 to C3:C6

Comment: The results are in different order because the URLs are requested at the same time and are ordered by whatever loads first. You can look for a way to have separate request for each URL, or look for a setting in the extension that will preserve the order.

Comment: Interesting, can you post a link to Webscraper.io documentation and how to download into Excel format.  Responders here shouldn't have to do this, saves effort if you do it once.

Comment: You can find it here: http://webscraper.io/documentation. I use it only for sites with captcha for every few pages (Which I enter manually) otherwise I use import.io or scrapy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to use `Sort` method of `Range` object with its `OrderCustom` parameter

```
Sub SortByUrls()
    Dim rngToSort As Range, keysToSort As Range

    With Worksheets("Urls") '<--| change "Urls" with your actual sheet name
        Set rngToSort = .Range("C2:D6") '<--| range to be sorted
        Set keysToSort = .Range("C2") '<--| first cell of the column to sort

        Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=.Range("A2:A6").value '<--| add your sorting custom list as the previous Url names range

        .sort.SortFields.Clear '<--| clear any preceeding sorting settings
        rngToSort.sort Key1:=keysToSort, Order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlGuess, _
            OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount '<--| delete your sorting custom list
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Avinash: did you get through it?

Comment: Thanks for great help. I'm new to stackoverflow and thinking my question is not answered. Just tried it, working great. Thank-you very much once again.

Comment: You are welcome. Once you post a question be sure to come back regularly and check it, both for possibly getting your answer (people could be busy...)  and give proper feedback. Good coding!